# Portfolio Optimization in R: error

Tags: r, portfolio

I don't have much experience in R but I am trying to run a constrained portfolio optimization with R based on fPortfolio package. Using the function portfolioFrontier I get an error message:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(getMu(Data))) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

My code:

```
#specs
spec <- portfolioSpec()
setNFrontierPoints(spec)<-200
setRiskFreeRate(spec)<-0.001366179
constraints<-c("Long only", "maxW[1]=.05","maxW[2]=.25")
setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS)))
#analysis
portfolioConstraints(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS), spec, constraints)
portfolioData(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS), spec = portfolioSpec())
efficientPortfolio(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS), spec, constraints)

frontier <- portfolioFrontier(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS),spec, 
constraints,include.mvl = TRUE, title="Traditional Asset Mix")

tangencyPortfolio(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS), spec, constraints)
minvariancePortfolio(as.timeSeries(portfolioXTS), spec, constraints)
print(frontier)
```

I found on the forum that someone had a similar problem but there was no solution. I know that the number of rows must be greater than the number of columns but this requirement is satisfied.

I'd appreciate your help!

Data Sample:

[image]
[image]

dput

```
> dput(head(portfolioXTS))
structure(c(0.00156666666666667, 0.00158333333333333, 0.00169166666666667, 
0.0016, 0.00158025, 0.00155, 0.00673371680501522, 0.00900662025078258, 
-0.0240575754236355, 0.0248764429466077, 0.00560202723890391, 
0.0141166753754614, -0.0301780036878394, -0.00848891285361475, 
0.0444382350834758, -0.0335723121416733, 0.00238564176285805, 
-0.0603502320765891, 0.032911309501205, 0.0157910651749094, 0.0593749401684385, 
0.0061188298291901, -0.0166768949719553, -0.0753692400590273), .indexTZ = "UTC", .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", tzone = c(TZ = "UTC"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1009843200, 1012521600, 1014940800, 
1017532800, 1020124800, 1022803200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Cash", "Bonds", "Equities_dev", 
"Equities_em")))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) code/data per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description, with the desired output. Please only use screenshots to display something inherently visual and nontabular like a plot or a GUI menu.

Comment: I found out that it probably concerns the attributes of dimnames as there are two dimnames, one with rownames and one NULL. How can I make it work?

Comment: That sounds more like a symptom of the problem you already knew you had based on the error - which is that you need a 2D object and you have a 1D object.

Comment: My xts data file  is 2D object with 4 columns and 192 rows though.

Comment: Can you share that with us to make it reproducible? Use `dput(head(your_data_whatever_it_is_called))` and then paste the results at the bottom of your question. That will help us find the problem and fix it.

Comment: done. I'd appreciate your advice

Comment: Thanks again for that `dput()`. OK, so, now that I can run your code I notice that on one of the lines you typed `Spec` instead of `spec`. That's a typo I can debug, not another object, right?

Comment: **Update:** OK, so, good news and bad news. The good news is that (after debugging the aforementioned typo) the code runs just fine. The bad news is that the good news implies you've got a data problem, and while the `dput()` helped identify the problem it wasn't enough. So you could do a deeper dive on your own with the full data, or give a larger `dput()` with maybe the output of `str` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I just messed up too much with data, it works for similar dataset., so I will just run my data compilation again!

Comment: Good plan. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this option?

```
# Economist at Large
# Modern Portfolio Theory
# Use solve.QP to solve for efficient frontier
# Last Edited 5/3/13

# This file uses the solve.QP function in the quadprog package to solve for the
# efficient frontier.
# Since the efficient frontier is a parabolic function, we can find the solution
# that minimizes portfolio variance and then vary the risk premium to find
# points along the efficient frontier. Then simply find the portfolio with the
# largest Sharpe ratio (expected return / sd) to identify the most
# efficient portfolio

library(stockPortfolio) # Base package for retrieving returns
library(ggplot2) # Used to graph efficient frontier

## Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.3.3

library(reshape2) # Used to melt the data

## Warning: package 'reshape2' was built under R version 3.3.3

library(quadprog) #Needed for solve.QP

# Create the portfolio using ETFs, incl. hypothetical non-efficient allocation
stocks <- c(
  "VTSMX" = .0,
  "SPY" = .20,
  "EFA" = .10,
  "IWM" = .10,
  "VWO" = .30,
  "LQD" = .20,
  "HYG" = .10)

# Retrieve returns, from earliest start date possible (where all stocks have
# data) through most recent date
returns <- getReturns(names(stocks[-1]), freq="week") #Currently, drop index

#### Efficient Frontier function ####
eff.frontier <- function (returns, short="no", max.allocation=NULL,
                          risk.premium.up=.5, risk.increment=.005){
  # return argument should be a m x n matrix with one column per security
  # short argument is whether short-selling is allowed; default is no (short
  # selling prohibited)max.allocation is the maximum % allowed for any one
  # security (reduces concentration) risk.premium.up is the upper limit of the
  # risk premium modeled (see for loop below) and risk.increment is the
  # increment (by) value used in the for loop

  covariance <- cov(returns)
  print(covariance)
  n <- ncol(covariance)

  # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint
  # (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
  Amat <- matrix (1, nrow=n)
  bvec <- 1
  meq <- 1

  # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
  if(short=="no"){
    Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
  }

  # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
  if(!is.null(max.allocation)){
    if(max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation <0){
      stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
    }
    if(max.allocation * n < 1){
      stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
    }
    Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
  }

  # Calculate the number of loops
  loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
  loop <- 1

  # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
  # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
  eff <- matrix(nrow=loops, ncol=n+3)
  # Now I need to give the matrix column names
  colnames(eff) <- c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

  # Loop through the quadratic program solver
  for (i in seq(from=0, to=risk.premium.up, by=risk.increment)){
    dvec <- colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution along the EF
    sol <- solve.QP(covariance, dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq=meq)
    eff[loop,"Std.Dev"] <- sqrt(sum(sol$solution*colSums((covariance*sol$solution))))
    eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] <- as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
    eff[loop,"sharpe"] <- eff[loop,"Exp.Return"] / eff[loop,"Std.Dev"]
    eff[loop,1:n] <- sol$solution
    loop <- loop+1
  }

  return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

# Run the eff.frontier function based on no short and 50% alloc. restrictions
eff <- eff.frontier(returns=returns$R, short="no", max.allocation=.50,
                    risk.premium.up=1, risk.increment=.001)

##              SPY          EFA          IWM          VWO          LQD
## SPY 6.810936e-04 6.986904e-04 7.919993e-04 7.889955e-04 2.855759e-05
## EFA 6.986904e-04 8.825046e-04 8.166626e-04 9.612606e-04 4.221047e-05
## IWM 7.919993e-04 8.166626e-04 1.083438e-03 9.426306e-04 1.195884e-05
## VWO 7.889955e-04 9.612606e-04 9.426306e-04 1.339355e-03 3.826838e-05
## LQD 2.855759e-05 4.221047e-05 1.195884e-05 3.826838e-05 1.085459e-04
## HYG 3.224162e-04 3.515984e-04 3.832917e-04 3.891801e-04 8.093112e-05
##              HYG
## SPY 3.224162e-04
## EFA 3.515984e-04
## IWM 3.832917e-04
## VWO 3.891801e-04
## LQD 8.093112e-05
## HYG 2.975042e-04

# Find the optimal portfolio
eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe==max(eff$sharpe),]

# graph efficient frontier
# Start with color scheme
ealred <- "#7D110C"
ealtan <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark <- "#423C30"

ggplot(eff, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha=.1, color=ealdark) +
  geom_point(data=eff.optimal.point, aes(x=Std.Dev, y=Exp.Return, label=sharpe),
             color=ealred, size=5) +
  annotate(geom="text", x=eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
           y=eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
           label=paste("Risk: ",
                       round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev*100, digits=3),"%\nReturn: ",
                       round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return*100, digits=4),"%\nSharpe: ",
                       round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe*100, digits=2), "%", sep=""),
           hjust=0, vjust=1.2) +
  ggtitle("Efficient Frontier and Optimal Portfolio") +
  labs(x="Risk (standard deviation of portfolio)", y="Return") +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=eallighttan),
        text=element_text(color=ealdark),
        plot.title=element_text(size=24, color=ealred))
```

https://rpubs.com/JanpuHou/258620